# Effect of using multiple SPSite and SPWeb objects

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, spweb, spsite, sppersistedobject

I want to know that what effects will cause if I open SPSite and SPWeb objects more than once in a code file (c#)

I have a implementation like below, can anyone tell me that what effects will it cause on my overall site performance ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
               var subjectList = GetSubjectData();
                HdnAllSubjects.Value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(subjectList);
                GenerateGrid();
                FillGrid(0, string.Empty); 

            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException.Log(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
} 

 private List<IdValuePair> GetSubjectData()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
            }
        }
}

 private void GenerateGrid()
    {
        // some lines of codes here 
    }

public void FillGrid(int currentPageNumber, string pagingInfo)
{
    try
    {
        // Dstring subjectString = string.Empty;
        using (SPSite ospsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb ospweb = ospsite.OpenWeb())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thannks

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple: open as many `SPSite`/`SPWeb` as you can. opening these SharePoint objects has a high cost (the highest in all SP Object Model): these are the objects that hold the connections to the DB. And each time you open them, a "huge" amount of data goes between the DB and the front-end, and is then loaded into memory on the front-end.

In addition, there's no point in opening these objects in your code: you're only re-opening the contextual objects (`SPContext.Current.Web`). No elevation, and not another site collection: you're wasting resources for nothing at all. `SPContext.Current.Web` exists for such situations: an object is being opened by SharePoint at the begin of the page lifecycle, and will automatically dispoed at the end; meanwhile, every component that wants access to it can do it with no cost at all.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have a query that i was asked during interview.
why we need to dispose SPWeb and SPSite objects only why not SPList and others objects...?

Comment: `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects are the ones that hold an `SPRequest` instance. `SPRequest` is responsible for all DB connections and requests: so, even if you want to retrieve properties of a list or get list items, it goes through that `SPRequest`. Also, the `SPRequest` is a wrapper around COM objects (a legacy from SP2001): that's why it needs explicit disposal: to release the COM objects.